# ¿Que funcionalidad tiene esta línea de código?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios, redux

```javascript
filterOption={(input, option) => 
    option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
}
```

En un proyecto de React tengo un `select` donde usa una propiedad y es una expresión larga que no puedo llegar a entender cual es su funcionalidad

```
<Select
    showSearch
    className="select-news"
    placeholder="Select a Crypto"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={value => console.log(value)}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
></Select>
```

Comment: Aquí explican cosas sobre este tema: https://react-select.com/advanced.  Supongo que en tu caso se espera un resultado booleano del filtro de true/false si se quiere en mayúsculas o en minúsculas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empecemos por lo básico:

La estructura `() => ...` indica que se va a realizar una función de una sola línea.

`(arg1, arg2, ... argn)` indica que la función está recibiendo parámetros para operar.

Yéndonos a la instrucción, el operador `>=` es una comparación *"mayor que"* que solo puede devolver dos valores posibles: *verdadero* (`true`) o *falso* (`false`), porque "10 *es* mayor que 5", "2 *es* mayor que *o igual* a 2" pero "-1 *no es* mayor o igual a 0". Por lo tanto, sabemos que lo que va a devolver la función es un valor *lógico* (en inglés el término es *boolean*).

```
(input, option) => option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
```

`option` es un parámetro que recibe (consulta la documentación del componente) la función, y asume que tendrá una propiedad `children` y que será texto.

La función `toLowerCase()` convierte un texto a minúsculas.

La función `indexOf` de un texto encuentra la posición de la *primera* aparición de un texto (definido en su parámetro) en otro texto. Por ejemplo:

```
"hola mundo".indexOf("mundo")
```

devolverá `5`, porque es la posición desde el inicio del texto (en base 0) del texto buscado:

```
"hola mundo"
      ^
 012345
```

Pero si no encuentra el texto buscado, devolverá `-1`.

Por lo tanto, esta es la secuencia que sigue la función:

1. Recibe dos parámetros, un texto por buscar (`input`) y un parámetro dónde buscar (`option`).
2. El texto dónde buscar será la propiedad `children` del parámetro `option`.
3. Convertirá a minúsculas tanto el texto a buscar (`input`) como el texto en el que va a buscar (`option.children`).
   *¿Por qué los convierte a minúsculas?* Porque así no importará si el texto o la búsqueda tienen mayúsculas y/o minúsculas, haciendo que "Hola", "HOLA", "HolA", "holA", "hola", etc. sean iguales.
4. Va a buscar la posición del texto buscado dentro del texto a buscar (`indexOf`).
5. Comparará el resultado de la búsqueda a ver si es *mayor que o igual a* 0.
6. Si el texto fue encontrado, la posición será por lo menos 0, y la comparación será *verdadera*.
7. Si el texto **NO** fue encontrado, el resultado de `indexOf` será -1, y al comparar `-1 >= 0` el resultado será *falso*.
8. El resultado de esta función será entregado al componente en su propiedad `filterOption`.

---

Espero que esta explicación sea lo suficientemente clara.